# How do I get the a value for a dictionary in an array?

Tags: ios, nsarray, nsdictionary

My web service returns this array:

[{"username":"xcodeSim","PUNTOS":"5"}]

And what I do is put them into an NSMutableArray via addObject and at the end I get this:

```
( <---NSMutableArray Opening
        ( <---What about this?
                { <----NSDictionary Opening
            PUNTOS = 5;
            username = xcodeSim;
        } <----NSDictionary Closing
    ),
        ( <---What about this?
                { <----NSDictionary Opening
            PUNTOS = 5;
            username = dannyrodri;
        } <----NSDictionary Closing
    )
) <---NSMutableArray Closing
```

This is an array with 2 objects in it.  But those two objects appear to be arrays, each with 1 dictionary in it, correct?

Comment: `[{"username":"xcodeSim","PUNTOS":"5"}]` is not an "array" itself, you are creating array by parsing this text and somewhere you do create nested arrays.

Comment: You got what you asked for.  The JSON parser returned an NSArray containing an NSDictionary, and you apparently inserted two copies of that array inside your own mutable array.  *Please* go to json.org and spend 5 minutes studying the JSON syntax to understand.

Comment: @HotLicks thx, but I didnt get 2 copies, I got 2 different dictionaries, which is what I needed.  There are actually more dictionaries in there.  I figured out the problem which was that I was adding the entire array returned for each user, into the NSMutableArray.  What I had to do was just get the dictionary in that returned array and put that into the NSMutableArray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You are correct. You are adding an array which contains only one object to another Array.
If you need to take the first dictionary you want something like:

```
NSMutableDictionary *dic = (NSMutableDictionary *)[[yourArray objectAtIndex:0] objectAtIndex:0];
```

Comment: Thanks @MidhunMP thats exactly what I ended up doing.  thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a JSON response. You may want to look into [Apple's Documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Or use a third party such as [JSONKit](https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit)

These solutions will help you serialize/deserialize the response with ease

Comment: Seriously down vote? Clearly the author is trying to get a JSON response and wants to make into a collection....

Comment: I dont know what a down vote is, but apparently it seemed important for you to give me one, I guess you know what it means and it makes you feel important. I guess someone felt compelled to belittle my question. I guess it takes being a parent to simply "answer a question for someone's sake" instead of putting him down.  Thanks anyway!